# No symbol table. Press any key to continue

Tags: login-screen, 16.10

Whenever I boot Ubuntu 16.10, just before the Plymouth screen, I'm seeing this message:

```
No symbol table found. 
Press any key to continue...
```

and it remains there for a minute or so before showing me the log in screen. If I press any key it will be stuck for ever and I'll have to restart the computer.

Any help is appreciated..

Comment: See also [Bug #1633839 “No symbol table. Press any key to continue” : Bugs : linux package : Ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1633839)

Comment: Found my particular problem in a Kubuntu forum in which a user reported his error--which I had repeated. He'd forgotten which of several hard drives he'd installed on. I followed the fdisk step here, but jumped at the indication which confirmed the drive I already had in my head. However, by the time I found my mistake, which I cannot confirm now, I had started a Hardcore Reinstall from DVD... Double-check the grub install if this you're seeing this error.

Answer (score 24):

Try this one, first from USB/Live CD (if you can't access Ubuntu from HDD), and then, or directly from your "HDD OS":

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

This will list all partitions on your HDD. Find under the `Type` section your root partition labelled Ubuntu or Linux and its `Device` (like `/dev/sda`).

Then, do

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sdX
```

Where `sdX` is the device you found with `fdisk`. Note that you install GRUB to a drive, not a partition, so `sda` would be correct while `sda1` would be incorrect.

Finally, run

```
sudo update-grub
sudo reboot
```

Comment: I got this on an update from 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS; the steps you outlined eliminated the problem. Thanks!

Comment: This also fixed one of my issues on updating to 18.04. Thanks

Comment: Also had 18.04 upgrade problem. This didn't work for me, I ended up re-installing 18.04 over the old install.

Comment: Doesn't work for me in 18.04 (upgraded from 16.04). As it seems to work after I press any key, I'm not going to do a clean install. But a solution would be nice!

Comment: I installed my secondary hard drive with these steps after updating from 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS and it resolved the error. Thanks

Comment: It doesn't work for me in 18.04 (upgraded from 16.04). I installed the system on an SSD and the files stored in a larger HD.  No matter I press a key or not, the login screen will pop up in about 30s. So it seems not a big issue.

Answer (score 1):

I also got this when trying to update from 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS. However, when trying the sudo grub-install command as mentioned I get:

```
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: error: failed to get canonical path of '/cow'.
```

But by following these instructions instead I solved my problem:

[How to Repair, Restore, or Reinstall Grub 2 with a Ubuntu Live CD or USB](https://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd)