# How to try Ubuntu 18.04 Live Server?

Tags: boot, dvd

I downloaded [an Ubuntu 18.04 Live Server ISO](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/server).

I burned it onto a DVD-RW.
I can boot from that DVD-RW.
I press "tab" while booting as described [here](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver): *If you act quickly enough, hitting the TAB key you will bring up the boot menu where you can choose to simply just try Ubuntu without installation.*  (Also described [here](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/try-ubuntu-before-you-install#1).)

However, it doesn't show "Try Ubuntu."  It only shows

- Install Ubuntu Server
- Check disc for defects
- Test memory
- Boot from first hard disk

and F6 "Other Options" doesn't show "Try" either.

How do I "Try" without installing?  In fact, I want to boot, [fix this damn bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/837035/no-symbol-table-press-any-key-to-continue#909472), then boot from disk.

I looked at [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootFromCD) to debug, but a lot of it is about whether the DVD will boot at all.  It boots, but doesn't offer the option I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Server image uses a different installer from the Desktop image.

To 'Try Ubuntu' in the Server image,

- First, enter the installer (you are not yet committing to an install)
- Then, look for the "Help" menu in the upper right corner.
- The option to open a Live shell environment is in that Help menu.

Answer (score 22):

To get to the "live" part of the live server, you have to choose "Install", then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>-<kbd>F6</kbd> to get to another TTY, where you will be given a shell.

Source: [Installing using the live server installer](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/installing-live-server.html)

> If you need to at any time during the installation you can switch to a different console (by pressing Ctrl-Alt-F<n> or Ctrl-Alt-Right) to get access to a shell.

Comment: Just thought I'd add, you can use Right Ctrl + F2 - F6 in VirtualBox. Then, `sudo -s` to elevate to root (which is passwordless).

Comment: Update for 20.04: the terminal is available from the server installer via `F2` key without `Ctrl+Alt` etc (also you can navigate to "Help" menu, and find it there). Not sure if the same is true for 18.04 though.