# How to try Ubuntu Server

Tags: server

I want to try the Ubuntu server without installation, but when I reach the step of booting from a USB stick, it shows me "Try or install Ubuntu server" in the same choice as the below photo.

When I chose that choice it installs Ubuntu:

[image: GRUB menu screen showing two entries, "Try or Install Ubuntu Server" and "Test memory"]

Comment: Related: [How to try Ubuntu 18.04 Live Server?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1052835/301745)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Boot up with the live server ISO image, you can choose "Enter shell" from the [Help] menu on top-right:

[image]

This is about as much as you'll get on a fully installed Ubuntu Server system. No desktop, no GUI, and a shell right away (except on an installed system you'll have to log in with your username and password). This environment comes with a minimal set for installing Ubuntu Server, and additional software can be installed online as usual with `apt install`.

[image]

This is also useful as a recovery environment to repair or modify an offline Ubuntu Server system, although I personally prefer ArchISO for this purpose.

Answer (score 3):

### Ubuntu Server in a virtual machine

If your computer is powerful enough, you can install Ubuntu Server into a virtual machine (use for example VirtualBox). A basic Ubuntu Server needs less CPU and RAM than Ubuntu Desktop, so you are likely to succeed according to the advice by @matigo.

### Ubuntu Server in an external drive

It is also possible, and actually quite easy, to install Ubuntu Server into an external drive, a fast USB 3 pendrive or even better an SSD connected via USB or eSATA.

You can extract and clone a compressed image file into the target drive. Please notice that the whole drive will be used, so avoid writing to your internal drive. This method is described at [this link to a thread at the Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2474692). Before using the method, please read the whole thread. I suggest that you use the Jammy version,

[cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-server/jammy/daily-preinstalled/current/](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-server/jammy/daily-preinstalled/current/)

[Of course] it is also possible to use the installer and install Ubuntu Server into an external drive. It provides more options, but is also more complicated.